# I can't start a new flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am trying to start a new flutter projetc on android studio but i can't do nothing, look what appears [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngy18.png)
When i run "flutter doctor" it's like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl4Oz.png).

Comment: Have you tried to click the Next button in the bottom right corner?

Comment: Hi! To be really honest i tried yesterday and showed up something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/cYxoABw.png)

But i've tried very recently and now it's appearing the right thing, i guess ([look](https://i.imgur.com/eBH6sOV.png)

Answer (score 1):

you can create a flutter project from the console just open windows console in the folder you want to create a project in and write `flutter create project name` and write name with small letters

Comment: Thanks for helping! I haven't needed to do what you said, but i will try too